# The difference between leaving a random.randit variable out of a for loop and inserting it into the loop

Tags: python-3.x, dice

I have just undertaken learning python. Thus, I constantly experience confusion.
Let me illustrate my question with an example. I want to carry out a coin flipping simulation

I start out by defining head and tail

```
c=random.randint(0,1)

for i in range(10):
    print(c)
```

In this case the program returns identical outputs. It returns ten 1 values or ten 1 values. However if a add some adjustment by shifting the variable into the loop like this

```
for i in range(10):
    c=random.randint(0,1)
    print(c)
```

Then I receive what I expect.The program generates either 1 or 0 value 10 times randomly. I haven't understood why it acts like this. Can you walk me through please?

I desired to have 10 random values of integers 1 or 0. I ended up either having either 10 0 values or 1 values.

Comment: It is because in first approach, variable `c` is populated with return of `random.randint()` once and you print that same value over and over. However in second approach, you call the function and store it in variable `c` and print this value.

Comment: In the first example `c` does not change.